# Cosine similarity when one of vectors is all zeros

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, cosine-similarity

How to express the cosine similarity ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity )

when one of the vectors is all zeros?

v1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

v2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

When we calculate according to the classic formula we get division by zero:

```
Let d1 = 0 0 0 0 0 0
Let d2 = 1 1 1 1 1 1
Cosine Similarity (d1, d2) =  dot(d1, d2) / ||d1|| ||d2||dot(d1, d2) = (0)*(1) + (0)*(1) + (0)*(1) + (0)*(1) + (0)*(1) + (0)*(1) = 0

||d1|| = sqrt((0)^2 + (0)^2 + (0)^2 + (0)^2 + (0)^2 + (0)^2) = 0

||d2|| = sqrt((1)^2 + (1)^2 + (1)^2 + (1)^2 + (1)^2 + (1)^2) = 2.44948974278

Cosine Similarity (d1, d2) = 0 / (0) * (2.44948974278)
                           = 0 / 0
```

I want to use this similarity measure in a clustering application.
And I often will need to compare such vectors.
Also [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] vs. [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Do you have any experience?
Since this is a similarity (not a distance) measure should I use special case for

d( [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]; [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ) = 0

d([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ) = 1

what about

d([1, 1, 1, 0, 0]; [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ) = ? etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**If you have 0 vectors, *cosine* is the wrong similarity function for your application**.

Cosine distance is essentially equivalent to squared Euclidean distance on L_2 normalized data. I.e. you normalize every vector to unit length 1, then compute squared Euclidean distance.

The other benefit of Cosine is performance - computing it on *very sparse, high-dimensional data* is faster than Euclidean distance. It benefits from sparsity to the square, not just linear.

While you obviously can try to hack the similarity to be 0 when exactly one is zero, and maximal when they are identical, it won't really solve the *underlying* problems.

Don't choose the distance by what you can easily compute.

Instead, choose the distance such that the result has a *meaning* on your data. If the value is undefined, you don't have a meaning...

Sometimes, it may work to discard constant-0 data as meaningless data anyway (e.g. analyzing Twitter noise, and seeing a Tweet that is all numbers, no words). Sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: What would a more appropriate similarity measure be in this case then? Hamming distance?

Comment: There is no context given. Euclidean distance could also be "more appropriate".

Comment: I don't see how cosine similarity can be equivalent to squared Euclidean distance. Squared Euclidean distance is strictly non-negative, while cosine similarity can be either positive or negative, ranging from -1 to +1. Cosine similarity can express correlation (+1) or anti-correlation (-1), which squared Euclidean distance can not. So how can it be equivalent to it?

Comment: @bluenote10 _cosine distance_ = 1 - cosine similarity so ranges between 0 and 2. Squared Euclidean distance _on L_2 normalized data_ can express anti-correlation the closer the distance is to 2 (max when unit vectors are exactly opposite). HTH

Answer (score 3):

It is undefined.

Think you have a vector C that is not zero in place your zero vector. Multiply it by epsilon > 0 and let run epsilon to zero. The result will depend on C, so the function is not continuous when one of the vectors is zero.